# Decreasing android studio 2.1 build time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I was using android studio 1.5 earlier and i just upgraded to 2.1.But after the update my builds are taking much more time(from 15 sec to 2 min now)

Things I have tried as mentioned here

> Enabled offline work in Settings

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

> in gradle.properties file @
>   C:\Users\.gradle (Windows)

But still no difference. How can I reduce the build time?

Comment: What is the JDK version you are using?@praticus

Comment: Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 79
Version 1.7.0.790

Comment: Installed the updated version of JDK and check if the problem persists or not.I faced the same problem but after updating the JDK the error was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

#### From official source:

> **Windows defender real time protection is causing instant run slow
> downs.** Add your project folder to windows defender's list of
> exclusion.

The video *(Instant Run - Deep dive)* on the official documentation page for [Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) has a mention of this at around 7:40 (timestamp). It is strange that they have not put this down as text.

Comment: Tried it but with no effect

Comment: have you turned on instant run at all? if not, that should be the first thing to do

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same issue with Android Studio

Please uncomment the line

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

and increase the org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m

in gradle properties file

also include

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in your module level build file.

it worked for me, hope it worked for you too..!

Comment: Made the change in the gradle.properties file and the build did speed up by about 30 sec but still off by at least 90 seconds compared to the earlier version

Comment: it will take time in first build but it will decrease time drastically in subsequent build

Comment: On my windows machine I run gradle build command first time after starting android studio it took approx 4 min 55 sec because I have 68 unit test cases, then I run command gradle clean to delete cache and again run gradle build command and it tool 1 min 50 sec.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried instant run?

Steps to enable instant run:

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run and click Update Project

ref:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

some more tips : [link](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/making-gradle-builds-faster/)

```
-Enable Configuration on Demand.
-Use Gradle Daemon.
-Newer versions of Gradle and Java are faster.
-Avoid doing expensive things during the configuration phase.
-Don’t use dynamic dependencies (`x.y.+`).
-Parallelize the build.
```

Comment: Instant changes is enabled.Many changes do get almost instantly refreshed(10-15 sec) which works for most UI layout xml changes.But Most even small java code changes still take its own sweet time to build.

Comment: @praticus what was the size of your app now? You should limit adding dependencies or third party libraries on your app, try to minimize it by just copying the class you just need instead of adding it on your dependencies.

Comment: Apk size is around 4 mb