# Android Studio Gradle Build takes more than 5 minutes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

So I have been working on a simple app in Android Studio and since last couple of days, whenever I click "Run", it takes more than 5 minutes to build. It didn't used to be this slow. I don't know why. It says "Gradle Build Running" and then app is loaded after 5 minutes. And this happens on both the emulator and on my android device. My grade version is 2.10
I looked up this issue and I have tried everything that other similar posts have suggested including:

- Adding --parallel and --offline to command line option settings
- Enabling 'offline work' in Gradle setting
- Adding `org.gradle.daemon=true` in gradle.properites file

Below are the screen shots.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Even after doing all these, my grade build takes 5+ minutes.
This is what was there in the event log:

```
10:27:57 AM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources,     :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies,  :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
10:34:24 AM Gradle build finished in 6m 26s 378ms
```

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have posted a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247256/decreasing-android-studio-2-1-build-time/37253276#37253276

Comment: I tried what both comments suggested on that post and still no luck

Comment: which emulator you are using?

Comment: I am currently running the app on Nexus 5 API 23 x86 (Android 6.0). But Gradle Build takes same amount of time (5 mins) when I run it on my Samsung phone using USB.

Comment: I have seen this problem before . You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36533928/5037958

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enable "**Dex In Process**" for faster app builds (for Android Studio 2.1).

> increase the amount of memory allocated to the Gradle Daemon VM by 1
>   Gb, to a minimum of 2 Gb, using the org.gradle.jvmargs property:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

Read about it here: [Faster Android Studio Builds with Dex In Process](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.7cwzq6yn2)

[image: dexinprocess]

Comment: I already have that line of code in my gradle.properties folder: it looks like this "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Comment: Yes, but that line is commented by default. Add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m` below it. I tried it in a project of mine, build time significantly decreased. It reduced from 17 seconds to 8 seconds.

Comment: I am having the same issue and I tried adding that line, no luck :(

Comment: I added the line "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" but it doesn't seem to have any effect. It still takes 5+ mins to build.

Comment: where i added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m in gradle.properties

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks! I also followed the advice here and used the Offline Setting and additional arguments in the gradle.properties file - this took my build from over 8 minutes to around 4 seconds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421/android-studio-gradle-takes-too-long-to-build

Answer (score 12):

Other solutions here have not helped me yet. I am seeing builds lasting **30+ minutes** only to end with `Error:Out of memory: GC overhead limit exceeded`. But I have made slight progress the past few days.

***Note:** I do not believe this is a solution to the problem, just a workaround until Jack works out the kinks*

I added the following to my build gradle:

```
android {
    ....
  defaultConfig {
    ....
    jackOptions {
            enabled true
            additionalParameters('jack.incremental': 'true')
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        incremental true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize '4096m'
    }
```

}

For some reason, adding

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to my gradle.properties made no difference. I had to add it in the `dexOptions`.

Comment: I'm getting the `Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'additionalParameters()'`

Answer (score 0):

In **gradle.properties** you can try using:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
org.gradle.caching=true
```

Hope this helps !!