# Gradle Scan Shows Slow Plugin on First Module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've done a gradle build scan and noticed that plugins are being applied slowly to one module in the configuration phase.  This module happens to be my first module.  Is it known that the first module is slower for plugins or should I be investigating that module for slowdowns?

[image]

Comment: even applying these tricks?            
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327617/very-very-slow-gradle-build-on-android-studio

Comment: Yep all of those are added to my gradle.properties I wasn't sure if the issue was with the plugins themselves initializing since the first module takes 75% of the time

Comment: Try to invalidate the cache and restarting studio. I faced a problem like your and this worked for me. Double shift and type invalidate cache/restart :) You can make a try!

Comment: These are scans from a command line build, but I'll give it a try

Comment: Show us your `build.gradle` files please.